# Building JSON dynamically using the Karate API Framework

Tags: json, karate

Here is what I need to build dynamically

```
{
    "recommendedAssociations": [
        {
            "StudentId": "PIP21|23455",
            "SchoolID": "23331",
            "Status": "ACCEPT"
        },
        {
            "StudentId": "DLO14|44445",
            "SchoolId": "23331",
            "feedbackStatus": "ACCEPT"
        },
        {
            "StudentId": "DEF66|43432",
            "SchoolId": "2331",
            "feedbackStatus": "ACCEPT"
        },
        {
            "StudentId": "334|11123",
            "customerOrganizationIdentifier": "2331",
            "feedbackStatus": "REJECT"
        }
    ],
    "recommendationMsg": "Student Acceptance"
}
```

How can I create the items dynamically?

Answer (score 1):

If you know JavaScript - you can use it directly to "edit" any JSON.

For example:

```
* def data = {}
* data.foo = 'bar'
* match data == { foo: 'bar' }
```

And arrays are easy:

```
* def data = []
* data[0] = { foo: 'bar' }
* match data == [{ foo: 'bar' }]
```

Here's another example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69041614/143475

For more ideas, read the documentation: https://github.com/intuit/karate#json-transforms

Comment: Thanks. However, I need  a way do dynamically create arrays, I should be able dynamically pass the number of elements in a json array

Comment: Sorry for not a clear question. 
What I am trying to do is dynamically build a json array, which has to be dynamic length.